# Which potentiometer to chose for LCD screen contrast?

Tags: lcd, potentiometer

I recently obtained DEM 16217 SYH-PY 2x16 character screen. [Here](http://www.display-elektronik.de/lcd-alphanumeric-table.htm)'s the datasheet. As far as I can see, its contrast pin should be connected to voltage source over a potentiometer. How do I pick correct resistance of the potentiometer for this use?

Comment: Wheres the datasheet?

Comment: @Dean For some reason, it wouldn't let me link directly to file. I linked now to the list of the datasheets for their displays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it makes a whole lot of difference. I've used a 10KΩ linear before which works perfectly well.

You're essentially making a potential divider, connecting your pot between your supply and ground, so as long as it's not too low value that it starts to draw more than a negligible amount of current.

Comment: OK. I'll try with that, once I obtain suitable potentiometer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with RT162-7 based on HD44780 (seems compatible to your DEM 16217 SYH-PY).
Connecting the contrast pin (V0) directly to 0 gives very reasonable contrast, even without a potentiometer or a potential divider.

Comment: Most HD44780 LCDs work reasonably well with 0V for constrast, but some will definitely work better (may depend on viewing angle) with a slightly higher voltage, so it is a good idea to include a simple potmeter. (and there are of course LCDs, esepcially wide temperature ones, that require a negative constrast voltage)